# need to run scala future sequentially

Tags: scala, future

In my akka scala code I am trying to mannipulate file created by the same code.

Process Flow

```
1. create a file A
2. use file A and create file B
3. use file B and do some mapping and create an ouput file
```

Now before step 1 is getting created, step 2 is getting executed and similar issue with step 3

Please Note: Step 1 and step 2 are time consuming like 2 minutes each.
To handle the situation I put Thread.sleep which let the code to go to step 2 however step is 2 
is more time consuming and putting thread.sleep(5000) is throwing Akka time out error.

Is there a way to handle the issue gracefully.

The gist of my requirement is I want to run the step sequentially.

Actual code below

```
val tmpDir = "src/main/resources/"
logger.debug("Import all documents to mallet...")
Text2Vectors.main(("--input " + tmpDir + "new_corpus/ --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords " + "--output " + tmpDir + "new_corpus.mallet --use-pipe-from " + tmpDir + "corpus.mallet").split(" "))
logger.debug("Run training process...")
Thread.sleep(10000)
InferTopics.main(("--input " + tmpDir + "new_corpus.mallet --inferencer " + tmpDir + "inferencer " + "--output-doc-topics " + tmpDir + "doc-topics-new.txt --num-iterations 1000").split(" "))
Thread.sleep(50000)

logger.debug("Inferring process finished.")
```

Comment: Where is the future here? Where is akka? Who is consuming these results? 
This does not make any sence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Await.result( yourFuture ,Duration.Inf)

Or use map and work with that is inside the map (preferable way)

```
val tmpDir = "src/main/resources/"
logger.debug("Import all documents to mallet...")
Await.result(Text2Vectors.main(("--input " + tmpDir + "new_corpus/ --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords " + "--output " + tmpDir + "new_corpus.mallet --use-pipe-from " + tmpDir + "corpus.mallet").split(" ")),Duration.Inf)
logger.debug("Run training process...")
Await.result(InferTopics.main(("--input " + tmpDir + "new_corpus.mallet --inferencer " + tmpDir + "inferencer " + "--output-doc-topics " + tmpDir + "doc-topics-new.txt --num-iterations 1000").split(" ")),Duration.Inf)
logger.debug("Inferring process finished.")
```

Or with maps:

```
val tmpDir = "src/main/resources/"
logger.debug("Import all documents to mallet...")
val firstFuture = Text2Vectors.main(("--input " + tmpDir + "new_corpus/ --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords " + "--output " + tmpDir + "new_corpus.mallet --use-pipe-from " + tmpDir + "corpus.mallet").split(" "))
logger.debug("Run training process...")

firstFuture.map(InferTopics.main(("--input " + tmpDir + "new_corpus.mallet --inferencer " + tmpDir + "inferencer " + "--output-doc-topics " + tmpDir + "doc-topics-new.txt --num-iterations 1000").split(" ")))

logger.debug("Inferring process finished.")
```